# Django virtual environment disaster

Tags: python, django, bash

I am working on a django app on my macbook with Yosemite.
My app was in a virtual environment.
I restarted my terminal and when I cd'd to my app it was no longer in the virtual environment and now doesn't run. And all my virtual environment commands give me -bash: command not found.

I fully recognize this is a very noobie question but I really want to work on my app and I have tried everything I could find on google and stackoverflow.

Please help.
Preferably with the commands I need to type from my command line - thank you!

Comment: Any chance you have your project backed up to a repository like github or bitbucket?

Comment: i was backing it up on github - I was trying to deploy to heroku when I restarted terminal - I had to revert - the file changes to make it deployable crashed my local host

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're using `virtualenv`.  If so, do you know where it put the bin directory?  If so, run `source bin/activate`.  After that, when you try runserver, it should use the correct Python instance.

More complete:
`source /path/to/bin/activate`

But I typically run `source bin/activate` from the directory that contains the related `bin`.

Comment: thank you - for whatever reason the env file was in the directory above where my project was and that is where the env directory was - when I cd'd to there then:  source env/bin/activate worked

Comment: on Yosemite at least - you need to add the full path: source bin/activate doesn't work

Comment: I'm running Yosemite.  `bin/activate` is the relative path from the directory I was in (which is the root directory of my project).  That's why you need to know where `virtualenv` is putting the files.  I'm probably running an earlier version as well, so who knows if yours is defaulting to a different location.  Some of our other devs specifically put the environment files in a separate directory, so that's another thing that has to be considered.  However, if you're doing that, you're probably familiar enough with the process to keep track.

Comment: You may want to look into `virtualenvwrapper` - it makes managing your virtualenvs MUCH easier, especially if you're just getting started. https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

I found [pew](https://github.com/berdario/pew) to be a very handy tool for managing your virtualenvs. Once its installed, basically, you can just do `pew new env_name` then `pew workon env_name` to activate an environment.

One of my colleagues use it on Mac OS X without issues.

Comment: sweet will check it out - I am mainly a node and meteor guy - this is my first django project and I am facing a steep learning curve - but I do like python :)

Comment: It's hard to learn both a language and a framework at the same time, but Python and Django are two wonderful tools to increase your productivity. Don't give up ;)